# "Генерится" or "генерируется"?

Tags: грамматика, глаголы

Which form is more appropriate in Russian:

> Эта страница генерируется автоматически. Пожалуйста, не редактируйте её.

or

> Эта страница генерится автоматически. Пожалуйста, не редактируйте её.

Since this term in this sense is relatively new, please, explain your point of you reasonably full.

Comment: I very much doubt that "генерируется" is "relatively new" - it is in use for pretty much a century already, way since electrification started.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov in sense "вырабатывается" it is not new. In sense - created automatically I guess it is new.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The form *генерится* is a haplology, similar to *близорукий / **близозоркий, знаменосец / **знаменоносец* etc.

Currently it's slang and not recorded by the dictionaries yet, but, being a haplology, has all chances to make it into the neutral speech.

At the moment, the dictionary form *генерируется* is more appropriate if you have to choose between the two.

Answer (score 5):

The right word is *генерируется*, being a form of *генерировать* (*создавать*).

Word *генерится* does not exist in Russian language.  It sometimes used in programmers' jargon, however it doesn't make it a proper word in the language.

I am not sure about the context you are dealing with, but why not just say

> Эта страница создается автоматически.

Comment: ...или "создана автоматически"

Comment: if somebody is used we can not deny it's existence - http://bit.ly/Orz6KR

Comment: @Olga Certainly.  All depends on the context.

Comment: @AleksG  - as for  "создаётся", you are right, this is fully acceptable here. There's nothing wrong even in 100% interchangeable synonyms, though in this case we can not speak about full interchangeability.

Comment: @shabunc Just because a jargon word is used, it doesn't make its usage correct.

Comment: @AleksG as you now there are different approaches for grammar, vocabulary, phonetics or any other sort of linguistic analysis, but we can divide them in two big parts. One branch can be generalized as restrictive and imperative, other roughly can be described as descriptive. Think of language like of multiset of statistical data. Whether we appreciate it or not, jargonims are part of the language. And stating that "такого слова в русском нет" - well, this is to strict statement )

Comment: генерится -- это падонкафское славечко

Answer (score 3):

*Генерируется*, от глагола *генерировать*.

сравни статью из "Большого толкового словаря" Кузнецова:

> ГЕНЕРИРОВАТЬ, -рую, -руешь; нсв. что. *Книжн.*
>   Производить, создавать, возбуждать. Г. электрические колебания. < Генерироваться, -руется; страд.

*Генерится* — это от глагола *генерить*, сугубо разговорного.

В том же Большом толковом словаре Кузнецова (ред. 2009 года) статьи для "генерить" нет.